# Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230. Lenovo Thinkpad T430u. Wifi not Working. Network-manager-applet not visible in system tray

Tags: networking, intel-wireless, centrino

my specs

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network DEAKTIVIERT   
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlan0
       Version: c4
       Seriennummer: 60:36:dd:0f:cb:52
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.5.0-27-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       Ressourcen: irq:46 memory:f4700000-f4701fff
```

Here's what I've tried so far

I checked if there was a hardware of software block, there isn't:

```
rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried to clean the interfaces-file

```
gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

but there was nothing writen in the file except:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I checked if the "iwlwifi"-module is loaded, however I'm not sure what the output means.

```
lsmod |grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               399576  0 
mac80211              555272  1 iwlwifi
cfg80211              208382  2 iwlwifi,mac80211
```

I assumed that the "0" in the first line of the output means, that "iwlwifi" is not loaded. So I tried to run "iwlwifi" with the "modprobe"-command.

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi -r 
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=0
```

I'm dualbooting Windows on this machine, and in Windows the wifi works just fine. The router also works obviously.

I don't know if this important, but I disabled my Bluetooth by default a few days ago  by editing rc.local with

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

(but the wifi worked the following two days)

I also installed VirtualBox a few days ago (since I've read about network problems after installing VBox, I wanted to mention this), but only tried to install Windows 7 as a guest.
And although the symbol for the nm-applet is not visible, I checked synaptic package manager and nm seams to be installed.

Your help is very much appreciated.

PS:
The output is in partly in German. DEAKTIVIERT (after the lshw command) means DISABLED, everything else seams to be the normal output.

Checking the message logs:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.427995] iwlwifi: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[    3.427999] iwlwifi: Copyright(c) 2003-2012 Intel Corporation
[    3.428189] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[    3.428193] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: pci_resource_base = ffffc900057bc000
[    3.428196] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0xC4
[    3.428350] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.618390] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1
[    3.618701] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[    3.618707] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[    3.618710] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[    3.618712] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TESTMODE enabled
[    3.618715] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_P2P disabled
[    3.618719] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 BGN, REV=0xC8
[    3.618840] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[    3.637741] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x81c, CALIB=0x6
[    3.637748] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Device SKU: 0x150
[    3.637752] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Valid Tx ant: 0x3, Valid Rx ant: 0x3
[    3.637777] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 0 802.11a channels
[    3.652582] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   74.692031] iwlwifi: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[   74.692034] iwlwifi: Copyright(c) 2003-2012 Intel Corporation
[   74.692146] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[   74.692148] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: pci_resource_base = ffffc900057bc000
[   74.692150] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0xC4
[   74.692276] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[   74.696282] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1
[   74.696623] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   74.696628] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   74.696631] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   74.696634] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TESTMODE enabled
[   74.696637] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_P2P disabled
[   74.696641] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 BGN, REV=0xC8
[   74.696752] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   74.713452] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x81c, CALIB=0x6
[   74.713456] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Device SKU: 0x150
[   74.713458] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Valid Tx ant: 0x3, Valid Rx ant: 0x3
[   74.713475] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 0 802.11a channels
[   74.713774] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
```

Comment: I suggest you try 11n_disable=1. Also, look for clues as to why it's DEAKTIVIERT. Check the message logs with: dmesg | grep iwl.

Comment: @chili555 : thanks. 11n_disable=1 unfortunately didn't work either is there anything specific i have to look for in the logs?

Comment: We have to look for something wrong which we don't see here, unfortunately. Everything, so far, looks just fine. Please reboot with any ethernet cable detached and run: dmesg > dmesg.txt. Hook up the ethernet so you can connect and paste the dmesg.txt file here so we can look a bit deeper to see what is wrong. http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ Then give us the link.

Comment: here's the pastebin link: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5708578/

Comment: Please confirm your virtual machine set-up. Is Ubuntu the guest or host? Is Network Manager running? ps aux | grep -i network. Does the applet appear if you start it? sudo service network-manager restart.

Comment: nothing works :(. the only thing running is glib-networking command. even after restarting network-manager. EDIT: I forgot to mention, when i go to the network settings I get this error-message: "The system network services are not compatible with this version". Does this mean, iwlwifi doesn't work with my chip-set?

Comment: i apologize for the gramatical errors, it's getting late :).

Comment: iwlwifi works with about every chipset. I would try: sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade and then sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager. Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement. Let's resume tomorrow.

Comment: @chili555 well, ethernet is also not working...i downloaded the .deb here http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=network-manager&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all since i'm running 12.04. and installed it manually, but now it's asking me for a lot of dependencies...can one somehow download all dependences at once?

Comment: I didn't answer your question about virtualbox yesterday, ubuntu is the host and I uninstalled all guests in the meantime.

Comment: I know of no way to download all the dependencies at once. As well, the dependencies may have dependencies. Of course, you may put as many packages as fit on one USB stick. Is NM running? ps aux | grep etwork. Does the applet appear if you do: nm-applet &  Have you considered a re-install?

Comment: @chili555 i Sound a method to download all dependencies here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1100816. I don't know if it'll work. And yes I have considered to re-install 12.04, but how do I know it won't happen again...but I've made a shell-script to install all the programs I normally put on a new install of Ubuntu, so it shouldn't take more than 30 min to re-install. It’s just that, after putting in so much time, considering it’s a “minor” problem, it kind of sucks, that I can’t get my wireless to run. Anyway, thanks for your time...